# How to add the single quotation marks for string (Alphabet) values?

Tags: text-processing

In file data is like below

Sample input:

```
123,xyz,456,abc
```

We need add single quotation for all string's only. First need check either number or string, For suppose first one is number not require to add the single quotation after comma next string need add the single quotation marks like below output.

```
123,'xyz',456,'abc'
```

Comment: What command do you use to get this output? Simple `echo` or different tools?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should [edit] it to include all relevant details. See [ask].

Comment: Are your numbers only positive decimal integer numbers without leading +/- sign nor surrounding spaces?

Comment: What qualifies as a _string_, what qualifies as a _number_? What do you want to happen for something that qualifies as _neither_? For instance, what should be the output for an input like `-1,0x2a,,a1,1e6, 2 ,foo,x-y, z,++`?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo ,123,xyz,456,,abc2 |
  sed "s/[^,]*[^,0-9][^,]*/'&'/g;s/^,/'',/;s/,$/,''/;:1
       s/,,/,'',/g;t1"
'',123,'xyz',456,'','abc2'
```

would enclose in quotes any comma-separated field that is not made exclusively of one or more decimal digits (that is empty fields like for lines that start (`/^,/`) or end (`/,$/`) with `,` or contain `,,` and fields containing at least one non-digit (`/[^,]*[^,0-9][^,]*/`)).

If you want to recognise arbitrary decimal floating point numbers like `-2`, `1.23`, `1e-2`, that would become more complicated and you may want to resort to `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q="'" '
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
      if ($i !~ /^[[:blank:]]*[-+]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?[[:blank:]]*$/)
        $i = q $i q
    print
  }'
```

That changes:

```
abc,,0x20, +2.23E-5 , x  y ,-2
```

to:

```
'abc','','0x20', +2.23E-5 ,' x  y ',-2
```

If you wanted to get

```
'abc','','0x20', +2.23E-5 , 'x  y' ,-2
```

instead, you'd do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q="'" '
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
      if ($i !~ /^[[:blank:]]*[-+]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?[[:blank:]]*$/) {
        sub(/[^[:blank:]]/, q "&", $i)
        sub(/^$/, q, $i)
        sub(/.*[^[:blank:]]/, "&" q, $i)
      }
    print
  }'
```

Comment: not sure if OP had thought of so many corner cases! if empty fields are to be untouched and any field with at least one lowercase alphabet should be quoted, then I think this would work - `echo ,123,xyz,456,,abc2 | sed 's/[^,]*[a-z][^,]*/\x27&\x27/g'` ...

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` if your input data in each fields are only digits or alpha:

```
sed -E "s/[[:alpha:]]+/'&'/g" <<<"123,xyz,456,abc"
```

Or in complex mode.

```
sed -E "s/[0-9]*[[:alpha:]-]+[0-9]*/'&'/g" infile
```

Input:

```
123,xyz,456,abc
abc123,,a-b,5
```

Output:

```
123,'xyz',456,'abc'
'abc123',,'a-b',5
```

Comment: That turns `abc123,,a-b,5` into `'abc'123,,'a'-'b',5` instead of `'abc123','','a-b',5`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fixed that, but `,,` in `abc123,,1-n,5` is null, should be `,'',` also?

Comment: Well, the OP's requirement are not clearly specified. I understood it as anything but numbers should be quoted, but there are plenty of other ways to interpret the question. It might be that the OP's input only  contains either all-alpha or all-digit fields and we don't need to worry about empty fields or fields containing characters that are neither alpha nor digits or combination of alpha and digits.

Comment: Thank you afshin exactly correct what i asked...i got the result...